# How to instruct linq to sql to update table columns to their default values on UpdateOnSubmit/SubmitChanges?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a Linq to SQL entity which emit the following two sql statements:

```
UPDATE [identity].[AddressTypes]
SET [Name] = @p4
WHERE ([SurrogateKey] = @p0) AND ([Name] = @p1) AND ([LastUpdatedOn] = @p2) AND ([LastUpdatedBy] = @p3)
-- @p0: Input UniqueIdentifier (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [b0cf44d9-c6ba-de11-b194-001e37f334ea]
-- @p1: Input VarChar (Size = 11; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Residencial]
-- @p2: Input DateTime (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [16/10/2009 23:43:28]
-- @p3: Input NVarChar (Size = 23; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [LUCIANO-NOTEBOO\Luciano]
-- @p4: Input VarChar (Size = 4; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Home]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.1

UPDATE [identity].[AddressTypes]
SET [Name] = @p4
WHERE ([SurrogateKey] = @p0) AND ([Name] = @p1) AND ([LastUpdatedOn] = @p2) AND ([LastUpdatedBy] = @p3)
-- @p0: Input UniqueIdentifier (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [b1cf44d9-c6ba-de11-b194-001e37f334ea]
-- @p1: Input VarChar (Size = 9; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Comercial]
-- @p2: Input DateTime (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [16/10/2009 23:43:29]
-- @p3: Input NVarChar (Size = 23; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [LUCIANO-NOTEBOO\Luciano]
-- @p4: Input VarChar (Size = 8; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Business]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.1
```

But I need the Entity to emit the sql statements like the ones below, where LastUpdatedOn and LastUpdatedBy are set to their default values. I guess I'll have to implement Extensibility Method Definition for "partial void Update...", but don't know how to proceed. Anybody out there could please help me solve that?

```
UPDATE [identity].[AddressTypes]
SET [Name] = @p4, [LastUpdatedOn] = DEFAULT, [LastUpdatedBy] = DEFAULT
WHERE ([SurrogateKey] = @p0) AND ([Name] = @p1) AND ([LastUpdatedOn] = @p2) AND ([LastUpdatedBy] = @p3)
-- @p0: Input UniqueIdentifier (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [b0cf44d9-c6ba-de11-b194-001e37f334ea]
-- @p1: Input VarChar (Size = 11; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Residencial]
-- @p2: Input DateTime (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [16/10/2009 23:43:28]
-- @p3: Input NVarChar (Size = 23; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [LUCIANO-NOTEBOO\Luciano]
-- @p4: Input VarChar (Size = 4; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Home]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.1

UPDATE [identity].[AddressTypes]
SET [Name] = @p4, [LastUpdatedOn] = DEFAULT, [LastUpdatedBy] = DEFAULT
WHERE ([SurrogateKey] = @p0) AND ([Name] = @p1) AND ([LastUpdatedOn] = @p2) AND ([LastUpdatedBy] = @p3)
-- @p0: Input UniqueIdentifier (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [b1cf44d9-c6ba-de11-b194-001e37f334ea]
-- @p1: Input VarChar (Size = 9; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Comercial]
-- @p2: Input DateTime (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [16/10/2009 23:43:29]
-- @p3: Input NVarChar (Size = 23; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [LUCIANO-NOTEBOO\Luciano]
-- @p4: Input VarChar (Size = 8; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Business]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.1
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

DEFAULT values in SQL Server are only ever applied when you **INSERT** a new record. They never get applied when you UPDATE an existing record.

If you want your `LastUpdateOn` and `LastUpdateBy` columns to be updated for each update as well, you'll probably have to look into using triggers to handle that. Or expose them as properties on your entity/entities so you can set them programmatically before the update statement gets executed.

Linq-to-SQL gives you a number of extension points to hook into - e.g. the `OnValidate` method on your entity class:

```
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action)
{
    if (action == ChangeAction.Update)
    {
        // set your LastUpdatedBy and LastUpdatedOn values here
    }
}
```

Or you could implement the partial method `OnUpdate(Entity)` in your class and set the fields as needed:

```
partial void UpdateEmployee(Employee instance) 
{
    // set your LastUpdatedBy and LastUpdatedOn values here
    ExecuteDynamicUpdate(instance);
}
```

Another option using a utility class for auditing is explained [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevesheldon/archive/2008/02/23/a-method-to-handle-audit-fields-using-linq-to-sql.aspx).

Marc

Comment: +1  ...or yet another option is to override SubmitChanges in a partial DC class, go through the change set, check if the entities contain LastUpdatedBy/LastUpdatedOn, and if so set them.

Answer (score 0):

I better handled my problem at database level, using triggers, since I needed these fields to be automatically updated and using server side information (date/time).

```
CREATE TRIGGER [identity].[AddressTypesInsteadOfUpdate]
   ON  [identity].[AddressTypes]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    UPDATE [identity].AddressTypes
    SET Name = inserted.Name,
        LastUpdatedOn = DEFAULT,
        LastUpdatedBy = DEFAULT
    FROM [identity].AddressTypes
      INNER JOIN
         inserted
         ON [identity].AddressTypes.SurrogateKey = inserted.SurrogateKey
END
```